# Drazin inverse of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

Is there an algorithm that computes the [Drazin inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drazin_inverse) of a singular matrix?  I would like to apply it either in `MATLAB` or `Mathematica`.

Comment: [This question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40802/computation-of-a-drazin-inverse) on MathOverflow might be of interest.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but since it seems to be quite old, I assumed there would be a MATLAB or a Mathematica code by now, that computes quite efficiently the `Drazin inverse` of a singular matrix.

Comment: @thanasissdr Depending on the size of your matrix and time constraints, you can use a [Jordan Decomposition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jordan.html) to calculate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this article:

> Fanbin Bu and Yimin Wei, **[The algorithm for computing the Drazin inverses of two-variable polynomial matrices](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.2100&rep=rep1&type=pdf)**, *Applied mathematics and computation* 147.3 (2004): 805-836.

in appendix there are several MATLAB code. The first one is this:

```
function DrazinInverse1a = DrazinInverse1(a)
%-----------------------------------------
%Compute the Drazin Inverse of a matrix 'a' using the limited algorithm.
%Need computing the index of 'a'.
global q1 q2 s1 s2
[m,n] = size(a);
if m~= n
    disp('Matrix is must be square!')
end
%-----------------------------------------
% Computer the index of A and note r = rank(A^k).
[k,r,a1,a] = index(a);
F = eye(n);
g = -trace(a);
g = collect(g);
for i = 1:r-1
    G = g*eye(n);
    F = a*F+G;
    g = -trace(a*F)/(i+1);
    g = collect(g);
end
DrazinInverse1a = a1*F;
DrazinInverse1a = -1/g*DrazinInverse1a;
DrazinInverse1a = simplify(DrazinInverse1a);
end

function [k,r,a1,a] = index(a)
%To compute the index of 'a'.
k = 0;
n = length(a);
r = n;
a0 = a;
r1 = rank(a);
a1 = eye(n);
while r ~= r1
    r = r1;
    a1 = a;
    a = a*a0;
    r1 = rank(a);
    k = k+1;
end
r = sym2poly(r);
end
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @emmanuel, I have added the principal code. The proof is very long and a cut and paste of its is not correct.